# Rational Power Question

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Show that if $a ∈ Q$ is positive and if $0 < x < y$ then $x^a < y^a$.

I was told to use the difference theorem for this question, but the difference theorem is only for natural numbers.

Comment: what is the difference theorem and are $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The difference theorem is: a^n - b^n = (a-b) * Sum from i=0 to n-1 of a^i*b^(n-1-i)

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^a$ and differentiate and show $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and it proves $f(x)$ monotonically increases and then it suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in two steps.  Write $a=m/n$ and $s=x^{1/n}$ and $t=y^{1/n}$; suppose that $0<x<y$.  Then
$$y-x=t^n-s^n=(t-s)(t^{n-1}+\cdots+s^{n-1})$$
so $t-s>0$; hence
$$y^a-x^a=t^m-s^m=(t-s)(t^{m-1}+\cdots+s^{m-1})>0\ .$$
The first step uses the difference theorem for exponent $n$, the second uses the difference theorem for exponent $m$, and both exponents are integers.